# How can I create a specific number of thumbnails from a PDF using Imagick, ImageMagick, and PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I'd like to use PHP, ImageMagick, and Imagick ( PHP Class ) to create thumbnails of a PDF. Some PDFs will only have one page, and some will have many.  I'd like to specify a number ( N ) of thumbnails to create, one for each of the first N pages in the PDF.

The code below works, but produces errors when the PDF doesn't have enough pages ( because I'm trying to instantiate Imagick on a PDF page that doesn't exist ).  I also know that ImageMagick can create thumbnails for all the pages in a PDF when used from the command line.  I'd like to mimic that behavior in the most efficient way ( memory and processor ), while controlling the number of thumbs created ... I only need a thumbnail for the first N pages in large PDFs.

I've looked at various methods to determine the number of pages in a PDF, and they all seem to be resource intensive.  Perhaps the code below is my best bet.  It accomplishes my goal, but bothers me because it results in some errors ... even though they don't affect the ultimate outcome.

Here is my code that currently works ( with errors when the PDF has fewer than N pages ):

```
private function create_thumbnails(
    $num_thumbs = 3     // how many thumbnails to create, defaults to one
) {

    echo "\n\n    creating thumbnails ... ";

    $num_thumbs_created = 0;
    while( $num_thumbs_created < $num_thumbs )
    {

        try {

            // instantiate imagick with the pdf
            $Image = new Imagick( $this->file_path_pdf . '[' . $num_thumbs_created . ']' );

            // define image file
            $Image->setImageColorspace( 255 );
            $Image->setCompression( Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG );
            $Image->setCompressionQuality( 60 );
            $Image->setImageFormat( 'jpg' );

            // size the thumbnail
            //  - resized relative to 8.5x11 ( assuming most pdfs are paper sized )
            $Image->resizeImage( 180, 232, imagick::FILTER_POINT, 1 );

            // save image
            $Image->writeImage( substr( $this->File->path, 0, -4 ) . '-' . $num_thumbs_created . '.jpg' );
            $Image->clear();

            $num_thumbs_created++;

        } catch( Exception $e ) {

            echo "\n  * failed to create some or all thumbnails: " . $e->getMessage();
            break;

        }

    }   

    $Image->destroy();

    echo "done";

}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the poppler library? http://poppler.freedesktop.org/ You'd have to run the pdfinfo command, extract the number of pages from the output string, and then you'd have it... Kinda roundabout, but it would work.

Comment: @MAtthew: but at the point he could jsut execute imagemagick from the cli and do it.

Comment: @prodigitalson The imagemagick identify command is way slower than poppler's pdfinfo, though. I agree that it's not exactly clean and straight-to-the-point, but sometimes it is just easier to bust out a cli command and refactor later.

Comment: @Matthew: true enough, but unless hes got root on the deployment target hes not going to be able to install a nonstandard library. ImageMagick however is often installed on shared/cloud hosting.

Comment: I have root permissions on my server.  I'd rather avoid a cli implementation and having to install another library if possible.

Comment: @prodigitalson Good points. If imagemagick does the trick and meets performance requirements, by all means, that is the best way to go. The only reason I suggested pdfinfo is because it is fast... Really fast! :)

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure if you open a PDF then `Imagick::getNumberImages` will give you the number of pages. Likewise at that point you can iterate over them with magick without have to instantiate per page. All this is speculation based on the documentation though. So youll have to test and find out for yourself:

```
private function create_thumbnails( $num_thumbs = 3) {

    echo "\n\n    creating thumbnails ... ";

    try {
        $Image = new Imagick( $this->file_path_pdf);
        $nbCreated = 0;
        if($num_thumbs > 0) {
           foreach($Image as $idx => $im) {
              if($nbCreated < $num_thumbs) {
                $im->setImageColorspace( 255 );
                $im->setCompression( Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG );
                $im->setCompressionQuality( 60 );
                $im->setImageFormat( 'jpg' );

                $im->resizeImage( 180, 232, imagick::FILTER_POINT, 1 );

                // save image
                $im->writeImage( $idx . '-' . $nbCreated . '.jpg' );
                $im->clear();

                $nbCreated++;
              }
              else 
              {
                 break; // pop out of loop we have reach our limit and are done
              }
           }

        }

        $Image->destroy();
    }
    catch( Exception $e ) {
       echo "\n  * failed to create some or all thumbnails: " . $e->getMessage();
       $Image->destroy();    
    }   

    echo "done";
}
```

Note i also changed where you have your try/catch. IMO its better to bail and stop creating images all together if there is an error because if youre dealing with a single file chances are the error will be thrown on each iteration, so its probably more efficient to stop on the first exception. You could easily wrap it in a different location, thats just how i would do it.

Comment: ( edit ) This works great. Thank youAs a caveat, I have not run any performance tests on this code.  Some of it is definitely resource intensive, but most image conversion processes are.  I'm not sure if any other aspects of it are causing problems.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to call `getNumberImages()` because we already limit the number of thumbnails to the number of pages in the PDF when we iterate through the Imagick Object in the foreach loop.

Comment: @T.BrianJones: Yeah... youre right about the getNumberImages call... its pointless since we are doing a foreach with an imposed limit. As far as performance... i think the only difference from using the implmentation you were having trouble with is that perhaps only a single page would be in memory everytime - but at the same time you have to open each of those pages and then destroy them ssperately so my gut instinct this is the fastest way to do it without invoking some conversion utility in the shell.

Comment: @T.BrianJones: There should also be an `else { break; }` too otherwise youre iterating over every page in the pdf even after you have reached your thumb limit. Adding that to the code now. Also moved `$Image->destroy()` inside the `try/catch`

Comment: After some implementation and testing, I've discovered that this method causes problems with PDFs that have many pages. Roughly speaking, based on my tests on a small Amazon EC2 server, it takes about one second per page to generate the Imagick object.  If you load the Imagick object one page at a time ( `new Imagick( file.pdf[0]` ), this problem can be avoided. This solution has, unfortunately, become unusable for my application, although it does answer my question. Thanks @prodigitalson