# How does one suppress error output when instantiating a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, instantiation, imagick

**Caveat - I'm not looking for a lecture about supressing errors  : )**

I am instantiating the Imagick() class in a PHP script.  It outputs an error when the requested page doesn't exist in the PDF.  I'm aware of the error.  I know why it occurs, and I don't believe there is a way to avoid it happening in my code because it's processor intensive to load the full file for large PDFs and I'm only dealing with the first few pages of PDFs ( [see this question if you think you have a solution to my Imagick problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261189/how-can-i-create-a-specific-number-of-thumbnails-from-a-pdf-using-imagick-image) ).

I'd like to suppress the error output like one would with a PHP function ( `@php_function()` ).  Perhaps this is not possible.

This is the error that is outputted:

```
Requested FirstPage is greater than the number of pages in the file: 2
No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).
```

How would I go about doing this if it is possible?

I've tried these two things, but realize the Imagick class is not outputting a standard PHP error here:

```
$Image = @new Imagick( $this->file_path_pdf . '[5]' );
$Image = new @Imagick( $this->file_path_pdf . '[5]' );
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `try/catch`?

Comment: It is wrapped in a try / catch in my code, but this is not an exception, it's actual output from the Imagick class ).

Comment: I just face the same issue. I am unable to suppress this "error" output. Catching exception works but "after" the message gets out. Also ob_start doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Putting parenthesis around the expression should work:

```
$Image = @(new Imagick( $this-file_path_pdf . '[5]' ));
```

`try`/`catch` only work with exceptions.

Comment: Doesn't work for this particular error output.  May be impossible with the Imagick class.  I may dig into the class code.